# Java - Iterate an ArrayList and Transferring the elements

Tags: java, iterator

My program creates a deck of cards and deals them all out to 4 different hands.
This is my code. It creates the 4 hands and deals the cards to each of them.

```
    Hand[] hands = new Hand[4];
       for(int i=0; i<hands.length; i++){
           hands[i] = new Hand();
       }
       for(int i=0; i<=Deck.size()+8; i++){
           for(Hand hand : hands){
               hand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
           }
       }
```

Now i have 4 hands, each with 13 cards, I want to iterate over the first hand, removing each card and add it to the second hand so Hand 1 has 0 cards and Hand 2 has 26. 
What is the best way to implement this?

Im self learning, so if you have a method thats different to what someone else has posted, i'd still love to see it :)

Comment: First, we need to know the specifics on the `Hand` class: how you get and remove cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the card data structure in your `Hand` class is an array or `Collection`, you can use a for-each loop.

```
static void transferCards (Hand from, Hand to) {
    for (Card card : from.cards) {
        to.addSingleCard(card);
    }
    from.cards.clear();
}
```

Feel free to replace the `from.cards` with whichever variable represents your cards.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Hand holds its cards into a `Collection<Card>` (i.e. a `List<Card>` or a `Set<Card>` for example):

```
public void transferAllCardsToOtherHand(Hand hand) {
    hand.cards.addAll(this.cards);
    this.cards.clear();
}
```

Comment: Don't try to remember everything. Learn to read the javadoc of the classes and interfaces you're using. That's how you will learn.